# Create a pandas map with two arguments

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm working with the "titanic.csv" https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data, trying to find the teenager survival rate from the age column. I was able to create a 'under10' series with

```
under10 = (titanic['Age'] < 10).map({True:'under 10', False:'over 10'})
under10_survived_1 = titanic.groupby(under10)['Survived'].mean()
```

But when I tried to do the same with teenager range, error was given.

```
teenager = (titanic['Age'] < 20 and titanic['Age'] > 10).map({True:'Teenager', False:'Not Teenager'})
teenager = (titanic['Age'] < 20 & titanic['Age'] > 10).map({True:'Teenager', False:'Not Teenager'})

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add double `()` for each condition, because operator precedence:

```
teenager = ((titanic['Age'] < 20) & (titanic['Age'] > 10))
                        .map({True:'Teenager', False:'Not Teenager'})
```

Alternative solution:

```
teenager = np.where((titanic['Age'] < 20) & (titanic['Age'] > 10)),'Teenager','Not Teenager')
```